# Meu href só funciona fora da tag php

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma parte de um código em PHP que compara se o nome do autor da postagem é igual a do email logado, e caso for, ele tem permissões especiais no post, como ativar/desativar, deletar e editar. Porém apenas o ativar/desativar está funcionando, quando eu coloco o o href dentro da função ele dá o erro "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\postagens\painel\index.php on line 64".

---

```
if($_SESSION['email'] == $post['autor']){
    echo 'funcionou amem';
    if (!$post['status'])
        echo '<a href="?action=1&&id='. $post['id'] .'" title="Ativar">Ativar</a> |';
    else
        echo '<a href="?action=2&&id='. $post['id'] .'" title="Desativar">Desativar</a> |';
    <a href="edit-post.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>" title="Editar">Editar</a> 
}
```

Comment: echo '<a href="edit-post.php?id='. $post['id'] .'" title="Editar">Editar</a>';

Comment: Não precisa agradecer, se alguma resposta resolver seu problema, simplesmente marque-a como aceita, Veja como https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgbXR.png

Answer (score 2):

**Ou você coloca a linha dentro do PHP assim:**

```
if($_SESSION['email'] == $post['autor']){
    echo 'funcionou amem';
    if (!$post['status'])
        echo '<a href="?action=1&&id='. $post['id'] .'" title="Ativar">Ativar</a> |';
    else
        echo '<a href="?action=2&&id='. $post['id'] .'" title="Desativar">Desativar</a> |';
        //linha colocada dentro do PHP
        echo '<a href="edit-post.php?id='. $post['id'] .'" title="Editar">Editar</a>'; 
}
```

**Ou fora do PHP assim**

```
<?php
.......
.......

    if($_SESSION['email'] == $post['autor']){
        echo 'funcionou amem';
        if (!$post['status'])
            echo '<a href="?action=1&&id='. $post['id'] .'" title="Ativar">Ativar</a> |';
        else
            echo '<a href="?action=2&&id='. $post['id'] .'" title="Desativar">Desativar</a> |';

?>

           <!-- linha colocada fora do php -->
           <a href="edit-post.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>" title="Editar">Editar</a>

<?php
 
    }
........
........
?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou aqui.